# Optimal Pig filter clause order

Tags: apache-pig

Say I have a filter clause like this:

```
filtered = FILTER rel BY cond1 AND cond2;
```

Say that `cond1` eliminates 10% of `rel`, and `cond2` eliminates 80%. Would my script see a performance increase if I put `cond2` before `cond1`? Should I break it into two separate `FILTER` statements entirely? Or is this optimization already done for me under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most pig jobs are dominated by IO (disk & network), and a filter clause needs to look at all records in `rel` to apply the predicate. So I don't think you'll see any noticeable performance improvement from switching the order.

Answer (score 2):

Filter Optimizations techniques are clearly explained in the pig documentation, you can take a look of `"FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier"` and `"SplitFilter"` from the below link.

```
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/perf.html#optimization-rules
```